# JQuery Mobile: how to not display the button focus halo when a button is clicked?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have buttons in my web app using jQuery Mobile.

When clicked the buttons have the ui-focus class added which displays a blue halo around buttons. The class stays there until another spot on the page is clicked. This happens in firefox, not iPad. I would like that this halo is not displayed.

What must I do for that focus halo not to be displayed at all ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the default css instead of hacking up the source. Just make sure your css file is after the JQM one.

```
.ui-focus,
.ui-btn:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found that the best way to do this is to give focus back to the page after your buttons are clicked.

```
$('yourButtons').click(function(){
    //Do some important stuff
    // ....

    $.mobile.activePage.focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well thats easy, just open your xxx-mobile-theme.css file 
and find the class **ui-focus**
and remove the **box-shadow** property manually

Comment: This would indeed work, but modifying the jQuery Mobile css is not a good choice. Proposal of codaniel is much better and the one I was looking for. It overrides the definition in the jQuery Mobile css.

Comment: @chmike Well yeah.. sorry i didn't provide the override example, good that codaniel point that.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me as I had a custom submit button and used data-role="none" on the button. The :focus event still had the blue glow so this worked for me. I wrapped my form in a div called myform.

```
.myform button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```