# How to remove the blue halo glow from jQuery Mobile input elements that receive focus

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm encountering the same problem as listed in:

[JQuery Mobile: how to not display the button focus halo when a button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851997/jquery-mobile-how-to-not-display-the-button-focus-halo-when-a-button-is-clicked/16971788#16971788)

However, I tried the accepted answer by "codaniel" which works great, EXCEPT for when you want the item in question to retain a regular drop shadow - just not that blue halo blur. When you apply the CSS rules shown in his answer to those selectors, it removes everything on focus - including the desired normal drop shadow. Any ideas how to keep the desired (black) drop shadow on focus but lose the blue halo glow?

Thanks in advance!
Cole

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the below CSS to override/remove the shadow.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/47rak/)**

```
.ui-focus {
 -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
 box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

This will remove shadow from all input elements. However, if you want, you can add it as a class to specific elements/input types. Assuming the class name is `noshadow`.

### Update

I made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/47rak/) to show you exactly how to remove blue halo glow from different types of inputs. All input types are wrapped by a DIV which accommodates major classes. Thus, any custom class should be added to that div using `.closest('div')`.

The below code removes blue shadow / adds `.noshadow` to input `type=email` only, leaving other inputs untouched.

```
$(document).on('focus', 'input', function () {
 if ($(this).hasClass('ui-input-text') && $(this).attr('type') == 'number') {
  $(this).closest('div').addClass('noshadow');
 }
});
```

I used `ui-input-text` to identify the input as all inputs have that class. However, it is different for input `type=search` as it has an additional class `.ui-input-search` and `data-type=search` unlike other inputs. So it requires different procedure to add custom class to it, this way.

```
$(document).on('focus', 'input', function () {
 if ($(this).closest('div').hasClass('ui-input-search')) { // or $(this).attr('data-type') == 'search'
  $(this).closest('div').addClass('noshadow');
 }
});
```

Comment: Cool! thanks guys. I think the solution was a hybrid of your answer along with Gajotres'. The !important tag was well... important. ;) Also using ".ui-focus" by itself to remove the glow from everything but then going and assigning a class to specific elements that I wanted the drop shadow to remain on worked. Oh and assigning !important to that class's rules also was needed.

Comment: Welcome @Cole we are glad to assist you :)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to remove it go with **[Omar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar)** answer.

If you want to have a shadow but of different color you need to change and override shadow color, like this:

```
.ui-focus,
.ui-btn:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px      #555  , 0 0 9px         #555  !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px   #555  , 0 0 9px         #555  !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px           #555  , 0 0 9px         #555  !important;
}
.ui-input-text.ui-focus,
.ui-input-search.ui-focus {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px           #555 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px        #555 !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px                #555 !important;    
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ywraY/

Don't forget to use !important, this is the only way original **`CSS`** can be overridden.  This **`CSS`** will cover every input element. You only need to find color that best suites you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Along with Omar's I was able to resolve the problem.

Comment: Ok, I just did. I haven't posted to SO much before so still learning the rules of engagement. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just write down regular shadow instead of no shadow.

```
.ui-focus,
.ui-btn:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px 0px;
}
```

Or use some other shadow of your choice.

Comment: Thanks Goran. I think the other two answers resolved my problem the best.

Answer (score 2):

Had it on multipe types of elements and this is what fixed it for me

```
* {
  outline: none;
}
```