# Change text input name attribute to match value from select list

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FyLr9/

I have a search function for a jQueryMobile 1.3  app that has the ability to add or delete filters from it. I need to get and store the select list value (can do) and then apply that to the search input's name attribute.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="js-select" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="search" class="select">Search By</label>
    <select data-role="none" name="select2[]" class="mySelect" data-theme="e">
        <option value="1" selected="selected" > Search1</option>
        <option value="2" >Search2</option>
        <option value="3" >Search3</option>
    </select>
    <div style="width:100%;height:10px;display:block;"></div>
    <label for="search">Search For</label>
    <input type="search" name="" id="search" class="inline" value="" placeholder="Search" data-theme="d" data-inline="true">
    <a type="button" class="closeselect" id="remove" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="right" data-inline="true" data-theme="d" data-mini="true">Delete Filter</a>
</div>
```

**JS/jQuery :**

```
$(function(){
    $('form').on('change', '.mySelect', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        //alert to show I'm getting the value
        alert (value);
        $(this).next('input[type="search"]').attr('name') = value;
    });
});
```

Comment: `[data-type=search]` or `[type=text]` JQM changes input search to data-type=search for markup enhancement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).nextAll('input[type="search"]').attr('name',value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FyLr9/3/

From Omar's comment just use the id to select the element

```
$(this).nextAll('#search').attr('name',value);
```

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign you spacing through me off

Comment: jQuery mobile is different. Take it easy =) check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972701/how-to-remove-the-blue-halo-glow-from-jquery-mobile-input-elements-that-receive/16973025#16973025

Comment: Thanks Musa, was not aware of nextAll

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work with jQuery Mobile? I ran your fiddle and added jQMobile 1.3 and it stopped working

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign Try `$(this).nextAll('ui-input-search').find('#search').attr('name',value);`

Comment: Awesome, just saw that in another post and was hedging that was the solution. Its the 'enhanced' markup jQuery Mobile creates. Love it.