# Change shadow color on failed validation jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

In my jqm app is no space for standard validation messages. I try to colorize the invalid textfields but can't really figure out how to solve the following issue:

How can I change the boxshadow of an input field if the validation fails with some timeout fade effect?

Something like

```
var fieldIsValid = false;

//validation failed
if (!fieldIsValid) {
    var myinput = $('#myinput');

    myinput.removeClass('box-shadow');
    //and the webkit-box-shadow, how is this called in jqm?

    myinput.addClass('invalidShadowClass');

    setTimeout(function () {
        myinput.removeClass('invalidShadowClass');
        myinput.addClass('standardShadowClass'); //
    }, 3000);
}
```

I can't find the section in the theme css, where shadow colors are explicitly set, how has the invalidShadowClass look like?

And is there a possibility to show the invalidShadowClass and remove it after 3 seconds for example?

Comment: add classes to `.closest('div')` i.e. `$('input').closest('div').addClass('foo');`. Check this answer for more details on input types http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972701/how-to-remove-the-blue-halo-glow-from-jquery-mobile-input-elements-that-receive/16973025#16973025

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked like a charm, thanks to @Omar

### script

```
function StyleInvalidControl(control) {
    $(control).closest('div').addClass("invalidControl");

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(control).closest('div').removeClass('invalidControl');
    }, 3000);
}
```

### style

```
.invalidControl {
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px #99200F /*{global-active-background-color}*/, 0px 0px 9px #99200F/*{global-active-background-color}*/ !important;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px #99200F /*{global-active-background-color}*/, 0px 0px 9px #99200F /*{global-active-background-color}*/ !important;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px #99200F /*{global-active-background-color}*/, 0px 0px 9px #99200F /*{global-active-background-color}*/ !important;
}
```