# jQuery mobile 1.4.5 and custom button image

Tags: css, button, jquery-mobile

I need to use custom png instead of default search icon of jQuery mobile.

The code I have for default button is following

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Search", "Home")' class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all">Search</a>
```

I try to redefine the CSS like this

```
.ui-icon-search { 
  background:
    url('images/search.png')
    50% 50% no-repeat!important; 
}
```

I see the image but cannot get rid of the theme CSS design.

[image]

---

UPDATE #1

I used CSS of the user **deblocker** and it looks like

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at it in the browser's CSS inspector to see what rule is overriding it? Once you figure that out, it seems you could just add the selector that would supersede that.

Comment: @Brian I mean I need to add/remove other CSS classe to see the image I need. So what is a  way to do it.

Comment: Your CSS looks correct.  My guess is one of 2 things: 1.  The CSS isn't actually getting included.  2.  It's getting overridden by something else.  If you look in the CSS inspector, and you don't see your rule with a line through it, then investigate #1.  If you look at #2 and you see a line through it, you just need to make your CSS selector take precedence.  For instance  a.ui-btn-icon-right.ui-icon-search would take precedence over .ui-icon-search.

Comment: @Brian When  I start to play with `ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all` nothing is working. So I need to know correct way to archive my goal.

Comment: When in doubt, inspect item using devtools offered by all browsers. jQM uses pseudo selectors `:after / :before`. You'll always find answers there. https://jsfiddle.net/jh1etf47/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQM is using the ::after pseudo-selector for button icons.

**First example:**

I'm not able to understand the size of your icon, so i'm using in this example a bigger one, 32x32px icon to show how to change also the appearance of the container button.

```css
.ui-icon-search {
  height: 48px !important;
}
.ui-icon-search:hover:after {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.ui-icon-search:after {
  width: 32px !important;
  height: 32px !important;
  background-size: 32px !important;
  background: 50% 50% no-repeat !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  margin-left: -16px!important;
  margin-top: -16px!important;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-1">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <a href='#' class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all">Search</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Second example:**

From your edit it seems you need a standard 22x22px button inside a Toolbar or Navbar, so the CSS is even simpler.

Moreover i added some *JQM no-frills* rules (Some credits [codaniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226698/codaniel) from this answer: [JQuery Mobile: how to not display the button focus halo when a button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10867311/4845566), see also this great post from [Omar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar): [How to remove the blue halo glow from jQuery Mobile input elements that receive focus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973025/4845566).

Feel free to check it out, IMHO it will be a somewhat cleaner, mobile-friendly look.

```css
.ui-btn-inline.ui-icon-search {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-style: none !important;
}
.ui-icon-search:after {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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) !important;
}
.ui-icon-search:hover:after {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

/* jQM no frills */
.ui-btn, 
.ui-btn:hover,
.ui-btn:focus,  
.ui-btn:active,
.ui-btn:visited  {
    text-shadow: none !important;
}
.ui-focus,
.ui-btn:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
/* speed-up some android  ans iOS devices */
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-1">
    <div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all"></a>
      <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="right">
        <ul>
          <li><button data-icon="home">One</button></li>
          <li><button data-icon="grid" data-theme="b">Two</button></li>
          <li><button data-icon="search">Three</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Third and last example:**

I'm using here a custom rule, alternate styles (black & white icons), 22x22px svg icons & png as fallback, tested also in older IE versions with `body class="ui-nosvg"`.

```css
.ui-icon-search-custom {
  border-width: 0 !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.ui-icon-search-custom:after {
  margin-top: -9px !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
/* white svg */
.ui-icon-search-custom:after {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) !important;
}
/* black svg */
.ui-alt-icon.ui-icon-search-custom:after {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) !important;
}
/* white png */
.ui-nosvg .ui-icon-search-custom:after {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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") !important;
}
/* black png */
.ui-nosvg .ui-alt-icon.ui-icon-search-custom:after {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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) !important;
}
/* Show me the tap */
.ui-icon-search-custom:active:after {
  filter: invert(100%);
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
}
/* jQM no frills */
.ui-btn,
.ui-btn:hover,
.ui-btn:focus,
.ui-btn:active,
.ui-btn:visited {
  text-shadow: none !important;
}
.ui-focus,
.ui-btn:focus {
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
/* speed-up some android  ans iOS devices */
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-1">
    <div data-role="header">
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-search-custom ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-left"></a>
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-alt-icon ui-icon-search-custom ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right"></a>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It seems like your CSS is very close what I need please take a look at the image I just added to my question and see the image I have to get. Thank you!

Comment: @Dimi you're better off creating a button from the scratch rather than modifying jQM styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.ui-icon-search { 
  background:
    transparent 
    url('images/search.png')
    50% 50% no-repeat!important;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Search", "Home")' data-shadow="false" data-theme="none"><img src="images/imagefile.png" border="0"/></a>
```

No additional CSS needed, but make sure, that you have right icon size.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using **jQuery UI Mobile**, you'll need to remove the search icon from `ui-icon-search:after` using `background-image`. You'll also want to remove the `border`, `border-radius`, and `:hover` that **JQM** uses.

### CSS

```
body .ui-icon-search { 
  background: url('images/search.png') 50% 50% no-repeat; /* Set Your Image */
  padding: 0; /* Remove Padding */
  border: none; /* Remove Border */
  border-radius: 0; /* Remove Border Radius */
  background-size: contain; /* Contain Background Image */
}
body .ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn:hover {
  background-color: inherit; /* Remove Hover Color */
}
body .ui-icon-search:after {
  display: none; /* Remove Default Search Icon */
}
```

You'll notice I don't use `!important` because I'm using [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to target the CSS using the `body` tag.

Here is a [working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJWmQy) that's using **jQuery UI Mobile 1.4.5**, and the CSS code above to get the results you wanted.

### Old Result

[image: Old Search]

### New Result

[image: New Search]

Obviously the [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJWmQy) I provided is not using the exact image you would end up using, but it should work just fine. You can always change the `height` and `width` of `ui-icon-search` to fit your icon better.